# Cant change the style of my site with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner at Javascript and been sitting with this problem for a while, somewhere i've done something wrong, but I don't think I have understood the concept about it.
I am trying to call a function from when i click my button, however i can do this easily with alert and prompt, works perfectly but when im trying to change the site of my website, it does not work. Would be happy if you could tell me where I am doing wrong and why please.

```
window.onload = saved;

function ChangeStyle(){
    var ThirdButton = document.getElementById('buttonThree');
    ThirdButton.onclick = ChangeText;
}
function ChangeText(){
    p.innerHTML = "CantCareLess";
}

function saved()
{
ChangeStyle();
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="buttonThree"> Utseende </button>
```

So i have plenty of text on my website, with heaps of paragraphs.. However, when i click the button it doesn't change all the paragraphs to "CantCareLess", it doesn't change it anywhere..

If i put in alert("Hello"); in my function, it works perfectly, so there's nothing wrong with my function.

Comment: What's `p` in your code, did you defined it? As you said that put a `alert` in that function works good, the only problem is that `p`, which you didn't show us how you define it.

Comment: This will not work because p is undefined. You need first to defined the element: var p = document.getElementByTagName('P');

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you out.

```js
< p id = "demo" > here is your text! < /p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">this is button</button >
  < script >
  function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace("text changed", );
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
  } < /script>
```

When I clicked on the button, 'p' will change text to "text changed".

Answer (score -1):

```
    function changeText() {
         var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
         for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
             p[i].innerHTML = "CantCareLess";
         }
    }
```

We cannot change the text to "CantCareLess" without selecting the p elements first.

So, first we select the p element using `document.getElementsByName("p")` Then we loop through each p by using `for` loop and then change the text to "CantCareLess"

Comment: Please explain what your code is doing and how it differs from the question's code.